# array operations in numpy vs matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a Matlab code that I have to convert into python. There is this one operation that I am currently struggling with. I have a Matlab array "edof" which has the dimensions 262144 x 24. I have a second array "dofVector" which has the dimensions 823875 x 1. The operation performed is:

```
edof = dofVector(edof);
```

which updates my variable and I get the resulting dimensions of the variable "edof" to be the same as before i.e 262144 x 24 but the values are changed.

I am trying to convert this line of code in numpy but have been unable do so.

```
edof = dofVector[edof]
```

I get the following error.
[image: the error message]

Can someone please help me here?

I am not including the description of the arrays here as this is highly technical and specific to my field.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy indices are zero-based. MATLAB indices are one-based. So if `edof` is identical between MATLAB and Python up to that step, you'll want to do

```
edof = dofVector[edof - 1]
```